# sas, prchange, reg ex, unstructured data

Tags: regex, sas

I am looking through someone's code. What does this piece of code do? I am getting better at PRXCHANGES and regex's. I am not a pro yet but still learning. It looks to me like it is replacing something like P.O. BOX with PO BOX. Does \s? mean optional spaces? and 0? mean 0 is optional? Also :? means : is optional? Looks like I may be understanding some of it. Thanks

```
   DATA _NULL_;
    X='P.O. BOX 123';
    Y=PRXCHANGE('s/0?\s?P\.\s?O\. BOX\:?/PO BOX/',-1,X);
    PUT Y;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very important to document when one uses regex , so that others can understand

As you see see in output

```
  P.O. BOX 123 is converted into PO BOX 123
```

Explanation of Some important  things used and use this link to understand in detail.
 http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003288497.htm

```
   ? indicates something is present 0 or 1 time
   example: "do(es)?" matches the "do" in "do" or "does"
     period(.) is another metacharacter it means any single character in regex
    to address period it has to escaped using \ it becomes \.
    \s indicates space
```

In prxchange this is captured group  "0?\s?P.\s?O. BOX:?" which is replaced by /***PO BOX***/

```
 0? can have zero or may not have in start
followed by \s that is space \s? indicates it can be there or not.
followed by literal P followed by . that is P. 
followed by space or no space and literal 0 followed by .
folloed by space and Box and can have : or not
```

This covers following few different scenarios/patterns

```
"0 P.O. BOX" will converted into PO BOX
"0 P.O. BOX:" will converted into PO BOX
"P.O. BOX:" will converted into PO BOX
"0 P.O. BOX" will converted into PO BOX
"P.O. BOX" will converted into PO BOX
```